# Are Pakleds really stupid, or is it just an act?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Samaritan Snare," Pakleds "play dumb" in order that the Enterprise send over its Chief Engineer to help with repairs. Quite possibly the Pakleds were truly dimwitted, but it seems equally likely that it was just a ruse, in order that unwary, generous crews send over personnel to help---only to be tricked into a hostage situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've hit the nail on the head. Based on Troi's perception that the Pakled are "insincere" and not really wanting technical assistance, we can reasonably assume that their malfunction was simply a ruse (a snare, if you like) to trap unwitting helpers (Samaritans) into lowering their defences.

As to whether they're actually dumb, the answer is a qualified yes. The official  StarTrek.com page for the Pakled describes then as "slow-witted" but by no means as simple as they seem. The implication is that they make up for their lack of *raw* intelligence with ambition and deceitfulness:

> A rotund, lethargic scavenger race who nonetheless are not as simple as they seem.  Their "found" technology has accelerated their abilities at a far faster rate than their understanding and maturity can apparently handle
>
> The slow-witted traders often frequent Deep Space Nine but little is known about them in the Federation.  The Pakleds have met at least the Romulans, Klingons and Jarada.  They are so deceptive it is not clear if Sector 006 is truly "far from home" for them

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) (considered fully canonical) goes even further, describing the Pakled Captain as intelligent, devious and possessed of considerable cunning.

[image]

Comment: Do we know for sure that the malfunction was a ruse? I believe the episode never implies anything beyond, being impressed by Jordi, they decide to take him. Not that the entire thing was designed to lure in helpful engineers?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski- Based on the simple nature of the repairs ("any first year engineering intern" could fix the problem) and Troi's perception of the Pakled ("They are insincere... It is not our help they want") I would say that the malfunction was most likely their own deliberate sabotage of a non-vital part of the ship.

Comment: But those data points can be interpreted differentially. Specifically, when you add the idea that they stole their tech and really do not know how to use it.
They did break down, they simple do not have enough engineering knowledge to fake that, but they are continually looking to acquire more power. And, to the best of my knowledge, Jordi never says something like, this busted phase inverter looks like someone hit it with a hammer/shot it with a phaser.

Comment: @jonatonwisnoski - I don't see how you could re-interpret "It's not our help they want"...

Comment: They do not want help, they want to steal technology and power. But the reason they currently really need to steal technology and power is a real one.

Comment: @Jonathon If you're talking about the character played by LeVar Burton, his name is spelled "Geordi".

Comment: I find the entire idea sort of contrived and implausible: if they stole technology, how did they manage to integrate it and use it? How did they deal with malfunctions? It is frankly a sort of "PC" idea. Moreover, that another species that looked and sounded mentally handicapped by human standards would in fact be mentally handicapped also does not make much sense.

Comment: @releseabe - TV is all about shorthand. If you want your viewers to quickly see a race as 'stupid' you can't make them look smart.

Comment: This has actually been expanded on in the first two seasons of Lower Decks, where the Pakleds become a major antagonist (aided and abetted by an outside party). Their appearances there further reinforce Valorum's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Pakleds easily outwit and manipulate some of the most intelligent species in the universe with relative ease, demonstrating the fact they are in fact genius. In order to con, manipulate and outwit someone of high intellect, requires an even greater intellect and to achieve this, you fool people into underestimating you, they would make excellent poker players.

Comment: The fact that they managed to briefly fool the Enterprise using literally the oldest trick in the book is hardly indicative of great intelligence.

Comment: Actually, your wrong.

Comment: Tourists in Gibraltar are regularly tricked by monkeys. https://youtu.be/pvfZk39eTww. Does that mean that the monkeys are smarter than they are?